# Sin acceso a funcion con addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Haciendo una llamada con javascript mediante addEventListener a una funcion crearUsuario, dicha funcion no muestra el alert. ¿Por que no esta accediendo a la funcion? Gracias

formu.php

```
<form action="crear.php" method="post">
   <div class="campo">
      <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
   </div>
   <div class="campo">
      <label for="numero">Teléfono:</label>      
      <input type="text" name="numero" id="numero" placeholder="Número">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Agregar" id="agregar" class="boton">  
</form>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

el app.js

```
var agregarContacto = document.getElementById('agregar');

function crearUsuario(){
    alert("funciona");
}

agregarContacto.addEventListener('click', function(){
    crearUsuario();
});
```

Comment: Podrias usar algo mas simple: <input type="submit" value="Agregar" id="agregar" class="boton" onclick="miFuncion();">

Comment: con el evento on click llamarias a la funcion deseada

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que cuando presionas el boton Agregar, este te redirije a otra pagina, crear.php.  Para comprobar que si esta funcionando puedes agregar esto:

```
agregarContacto.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    crearUsuario();
});
```

Comment: La verdad es que eso lo habia probado pero tampoco me funciona. Me sigue llevando a crear.php y no muestra el alert. ¿Alguna otra idea? Gracias

Comment: Ok, veo que mi ejemplo funciona bien tal y como lo publiqué. Lo que pasa es que despues tenia una consulta a una bd con un  <?php while($registros = $resultado->fetch_assoc() ) { ?> y esto hacia que el javascript fallase.
Gracias de todas formas por los comentarios